# Base class usage in c #?

Tags: c#

Good day. I am just wondering how to create a base class and use it for my business objects. The base class would have some attributes like IsNew, IsDirty etc.

1. What I want to know is how to
   inherit this base class ?
2. Also what does the 'base' syntax
   means ? Is it always required to use 'base' to access the base class ?
3. How many base classes can I have ?
4. Can you show me a little sample

I did google but it was sort of confusing. Here I would get a quick answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any class which is not sealed can be a base class.

To inherit from a class, the syntax would be

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass
```

in C#, the base keyword is used to refer to the parent class from within the child class.

Since there is no multiple inheritance i.e a class can have only one immediate parent class, base refers to that parent

I dont think it is always required to use base.XYX to use the base class. This kind of syntax is commonly used for constructors to call the base constructor or to invoke base members which might be over-ridden
More details on base [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Just a little question, would a new instance of base class be initiated whenever I make a new business object (Inheriting class)?

Comment: When talking about concrete objects, when you instantiate a child class, you have only one object and that is of the child class. It could be argued that logically, though, Inheritance (parent - child) being a IS- A relationship. when a child object exists, then a parent class object also exists as every child can be typecast to its parent - and has all the properties of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading how others have done it. One of the most popular business objects frameworks for .NET is CSLA:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_Scalable_Logical_Architecture

Basically, those frameworks give you an already made base class that handles all the common work (the IsDirty property, an identity field, etc) and you inherit all your business objects from it.

Here are some blog posts that shows how the CSLA base classes are designed, and some variants:

http://pavelsem.blogspot.com/2009/05/cslanet-introduction-first-business.html
http://madskristensen.net/post/A-smart-base-class-for-business-objects.aspx

You might even want to use some kind of framework and save a bunch of effort if you are not doing this just for learning purposes.

The author of the CSLA framework has several books on how the framework is designed and how to use it. They are very easy to follow and worth buying, in my opinion:

[Expert C# 2008 Business Objects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210192) (link to Amazon)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I am trying to follow this article here http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/maintaining_dirty_and_new_state_of_objects.aspx

Comment: Good luck, I would suggest: 1) start posting more stackoverflow questions with more specific doubts as you go through the article, and  2) if you can afford it, the CSLA book (by Rockford Lothka himself) is worth buying and reading: it explains how the framework is designed and how it works at level that is very easy to understand.

Comment: thank you mister Sergio. Yeah I might save some and buy that book. That article I posted is not related with CLSA though.

Comment: I think the book is helpful because it teaches you how to think about base class design, not necessarily because it uses CSLA. You can make your own framework after reading the book. But don't get me wrong I don't want to insist about the book: I know the book is not useful for you at this moment because you don't have it =)

Comment: Hey, I did not get you wrong. I will buy the book as soon as I save for it. It seems like a good read.